# Cannot match my pattern with Matcher.matches

Tags: java, regex

I've got the following pattern/matcher:-

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*'G3[IJC]{1}'.*");
Matcher matcher = null;

boolean matchFound = false;

String values = "";

for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++)
{
    values = attributes.getValue(i);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(values);

    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        matchFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find attribute values within an XML document that contain 'G3C', 'G3I' or 'G3J' but it doesn't work.

I've tried various patterns e.g. `&apos;G3[C|I|J]?&apos;` and other variations.

If I use notepad++ these patterns in the Regex find function work.

If i run a simple java class with a string containing some random text with any of these values included, it works, but if I put it in this XML document and read it in using a `SaxParser` then, no luck.

**Update**

Couldn't post sample XML for some reason. It didn't show up in the editor.

Something like this though:

```
<SOMELEMENT = 'G3I' SOMETHINGELSE = 'G3J'>
```

I did print all of the information out using attributes.getValue(i) where i is iterated over and it prints out the values I'm looking for, but the regex still doesn't find them, yet the regex finds the values when I pass them in as string.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show *any* interaction with XML, and you haven't given us any sample XML. You should separate the regex part from the XML part: if the issue is in SaxParser, you should be able to demonstrate that without any regular expressions at all... just print out the attribute values. If the problem is actually in your regular expression, then the XML part is irrelevant, and you should demonstrate the problem using hard-coded strings.

Comment: @David as you've accepted my answer I'm going to edit your question to better reflect what you were really asking. As [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) points out, this is not about SAX.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's what I did. Printed out all values using attribute.getValue(i). The value i wanted to find showed up.
I also tried hard-coded strings and the Regex worked. 
I tried both of your suggestions and they both worked, yet when combined they didn't I ended up asking the question here.

Comment: @David: So why didn't you *shows* us all of that? With sample data and a complete sample app, we could easily have helped you narrow it down. You should be able to post XML so long as you indent it like code.

Comment: Although the sample you've given us isn't valid XML...

Comment: Thanks, I'll know for next time.
Couldn't post all the XML for that reason and because it contains sensitive data and there's too much to take out. Over 100,000 lines.
I know the XML I gave isn't valid. The part in the apostrophes was the important part though. I just wanted to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you should replace `if (matcher.matches())` with `if (matcher.find())` or `while (matcher.find())` if you're iterating over multiple possible matches.

`Matcher.matches` will match the entire input from start to end with your `Pattern`.

In your case, you probably want to find one or more instances of your `Pattern` *within* the input.